# What HTTP response should I use if my Request/Ack/Poll fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario similar to [request/ack/poll](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/13/request-acknowledge-poll-with-nservicebus-and-aspnet-webapi/). So the client posts data and I send status Accepted back. Then a background process takes care of creating the resource.

The client can then go to the location of the "Accepted response" and Poll for status.

If the background process fails and I want to inform the client about this, what status code should I return? HTTP 500 is not that good since it could also happen if the call to the status route fails for any other reason, and the client couldn't tell the difference.

And also, what is the best code to return when the creation of the resource is still in progress? 200 OK?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a [media type](https://github.com/tavis-software/Status) to address this issue.  Here is a copy of the readme..

---

A status document might look like:

```
<status state="busy" progress="2/75" message="This is a message"/>
```

It consists of a root node named status and has the properties: state, progress and message.

Only the state property is required, and should be one of the following values : `{waiting, busy, warning, error, ok, cancelled}`

The progress property is a fraction that can be optionally used to indicate to a user how much longer we expect the resource to remain in a particular state.

The message property is a human readable string intended to qualify the resource state.

Additional information can be provided by embedding links within the status node.

```
<status state="ok" message="Finshed generating report">
    <link rel="related" href="http://example.org/report/99/output"/>
</status>
```

the JSON equivalent of this would be

```
{ "status" : {
        "state" : "ok",
        "message" : "Finished generating report",
        "links" : {
            "related" : { "href" : "http://example.org/report/99/output"}
        }
    }
}
```

The syntax of the links object in the JSON format follows the convention of HAL except that there is no leading underscore for the links object. The underscore is unncessary as this media type does encourage embedding arbitrary additional content, therefore no naming conflicts should occur.

The specification does not prohibit extensions to the content, however it defines no rules for extensions beyond the constraints of the underlying JSON/XML format.

**Media Type Identifiers**

The intent is to submit this specifcation as a proposal to IANA for registration using the following identifiers:

- application/status+xml
- application/status+json